# Espresso not uploading app apk to Firebase

Tags: android-espresso, firebase-test-lab, android-espresso-recorder

I'm doing some automated testing using Espresso with Firebase, but when I run my test and after the gradle building, when trying tu upload my test to Firebase, it just get stuck in "Testing started at 15:16 ...
Using Cloud Storage Bucket location test-lab-ra3b2kj4p5390-mhpzifkjb34r6/as-build_2019-10-03_15:16:05.798_RoOL ...
Uploading app APK ...", and it doesn't go further.

Comment: There's not much to go on here. Can you take a look at the Android Studio logs if they have some more info. Can you find them under **Help** -> **Show Log in Files** which opens your file explorer. Take a look at the **idea.log** file.

Comment: I was running other project, it was my fault, but now I have other problem, can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58227597/espresso-not-uploading-app-apk-to-firebase-getting-message-skipped-triggering