# Espresso not uploading app apk to Firebase, getting message "Skipped triggering the test execution: The provided APK is invalid"

Tags: firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab, android-espresso-recorder

I'm doing some automated testing using Espresso with Firebase, but when I run my test, when trying tu upload my test to Firebase, I get the message Skipped triggering the test execution: The provided APK is invalid, how can I solve it?

Comment: An invalid APK could have multiple reasons. Pls join the [Firebase Community](https://firebase.community/) Slack and join the #test-lab channel. The engineering team can take a closer look at your specific test.

Comment: This question should be for Firebase support